# How to make angular.js validation work inside a <form> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-validation

I wrote this code but it doesn't work when I place my app inside of `<form name="myForm">...` tag. What should I do to make it works! (whenever I place `myForm` inside of `ng-app` it works, but my app should be inside of `<form>`)

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div ng-app ng-init="myInput = 'ABC'">
        <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
        <h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>
    </div>
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/bsf6aoby/)

Comment: Have you tried `myInput.$valid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ngForm directive (here) in order to enable the validation services within it:

Like this:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate ng-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had `ng-app` tag inside `form` tag. So that's the reason `form` tag with `myForm` doesn't get compiled by angular and `myForm` would not available inside angular scope.

You should move `ng-app` at top most parent, mostly `html`/`body` tag so that you will ensure that everything compiled by angular & will stay inside angular context.

```
<form ng-app name="myForm">
    <div  ng-init="myInput = 'ABC'">
        <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
        <h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/bsf6aoby/)

> Its not good idea to create a angular application without modules. Ideally it should have module & provide that module inside `ng-app` directive. I guess you are learning that's why you had it there.

Comment: tnx sir, I know but I can't move `ng-app` at top most parent... I need another solution...

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh OMG, I thought that you are learning angular and thats why you created application without module.. Ideally in enterprise application you should make your application modularize..

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh may I know whats wrong with my answer, just wanted to know? The core problem haven't been explain at all in the accepted answer